# how to solve error QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display when using exec function for phantomJs using PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, phantomjs, ubuntu-16.04

I am working on a project where I want to use PHP and Phantomjs together, I have completed my phantomJs script and trying to run it using php exec function. but the function is returning an array of error list.
below I am writing my code of phantomjs and php

dir: /var/www/html/phantom/index.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.open('http://insttaorder.com/', function(status) {
    // Get all links to CSS and JS on the page
    var links = page.evaluate(function() {

        var urls = [];

        $("[rel=stylesheet]").each(function(i, css) {
            urls.push(css.href);
        });

        $("script").each(function(i, js) {
            if (js.src) {
                urls.push(js.src);
            }
        });

        return urls;
    });

    // Save all links to a file
    var url_file = "list.txt";
    fs.write(url_file, links.join("\n"), 'w');

    // Launch wget program to download all files from the list.txt to current
    // folder
    require("child_process").execFile("wget", [ "-i", url_file ], null,
            function(err, stdout, stderr) {

                console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", stdout);
                console.log("execFileSTDERR:", stderr);

                // After wget finished exit PhantomJS
                phantom.exit();

            });

});
```

dir: /var/www/html/phantom/index.php

```
exec('/usr/bin/phantomjs  index.js 2>&1',$output);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
die;
```

Also tried with

```
 exec('/usr/bin/phantomjs  /var/www/html/phantom/index.js 2>&1',$output);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($output);
    die;
```

After runing this i am getting below error

```
Array
(
    [0] => QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
    [1] => PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
    [2] =>  and file a bug report.
    [3] => Aborted (core dumped)
)
```

But if I run index.php file from the terminal like this:

```
user2@user2-H81M-S:/var/www/html/phantom$ php index.php
```

then it works fine.I don't know how to solve it. Please help.

i am using following version
system version: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
PHP version: 5.6
phantomJs version: 2.1.1

Comment: `I don't know how to solve it` What have you tried? a Google search of the error perhaps?

Comment: yes, I tried on google and tried many ways said by people but did not work anymore.

Comment: You should add what you tried and what didn't work so that people don't advice what you already tried.

Comment: above i have already mentioned what i have tried so far

Comment: Hey, last question, what search request did you use in Google to figure out things yourself?

Comment: Please read my question again you will get an idea what I have tried. and I haven't remembered what I searched on google.

Comment: *Sigh* This site is not Upwork :) Please start with googling `QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display` and work through the search results.

Comment: i know dear this site is stackoverflow.com and not is upwork.but if you cant answer Please don't argue with question.

Comment: I think I know the answer, but since you didn't even bother to accept my previous answer (but using the code anyway!) I'll probably won't waste more time writing it.

Answer (score 15):

Did you tried to set an environment variable on your server ? or added it before calling phantomjs ?

I was in the same situation and found some solutions:

a. define or set variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` to `offscreen`:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen /usr/bin/phantomjs index.js
```

b. or add this line into your `.bashrc` file *(put it at the end)*:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
```

c. or install the package `xvfb` and call `xvfb-run` before `phantomjs`:

```
xvfb-run /usr/bin/phantomjs index.js
```

d. or use the parameter `platform`:

```
/usr/bin/phantomjs -platform offscreen index.js
```

Maybe you don't want / can't make modification on your server and in that case you may try to download the static binary from [official website](http://phantomjs.org/) then:

```
/path/to/the/bin/folder/phantomjs index.js
```

and / or create an alias in your `.bash_aliases` file like this:

```
alias phantomjs=/path/to/the/bin/folder/phantomjs
```

> make sure that `phantomjs` is not installed already on the system if you decide to use the alias.
>
> *if the file `.bash_aliases` not exist already, feel free to create it or add the `alias` line at the end of the `.bashrc` file*

Some references:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=817277
- https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14376
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phantomjs/+bug/1586134

Comment: It might be random but I've seen a file size difference when using the static binary instead of the ubuntu package.

`- static binary: 852K`
`- ubuntu package: 879K`

for the same image / url...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem running phantomjs on headless Ubuntu 18.04 (on the default Vagrant vm install of openstreetmap-website).  Folloiwng Jiab77's links, it seems the [Phantomjs team says the problem is the Debian package](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14240) but the [Debian team closed the bug as wontfix](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=817277).  I needed phantomjs to "just work" so it can be called by other programs that expect it to work normally.  Specifically, openstreetmap-website has an extensive Ruby test suite with over 40 tests that were failing because of this, and I didn't want to modify all those tests.

Following Jiab77's answer, here's how I made it work:

1. As root, `cp /usr/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs`
2. Edit /usr/local/bin/phantomjs and add the line `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen` so it runs before execution.  Here is what mine says after doing so:

   `#!/bin/sh
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/phantomjs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    # 2018-11-13: added the next line so phantomjs can run headless as explained on
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154209/how-to-solve-error-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-display-when-using-exec
    export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
    exec "/usr/lib/phantomjs/phantomjs" "$@"`

After this change, `phantomjs` can be run from the command line without changing anything else, and all the tests that depend on phantomjs were successfully passed.